# Why does the w3wp.exe application pool continuously recycle during rush hours with the mscorlib.ni.dll module faulting?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, .net-framework-version

I have a problem that i have .net application works as backend app i have a problem that currently appeared after the amount of users has increased the applicaion pool recycles in rush hours continously and when i investiage i found  out the windows logger gave me the following error

Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 10.0.14393.0, time stamp: 0x57899135
Faulting module name: mscorlib.ni.dll, version: 4.6.1586.0, time stamp: 0x575a1299
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x00371983
Faulting process id: 0x1630
Faulting application start time: 0x01d3e3a513e484f0
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\SysWoW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\mscorlib\40571abae9422cd2ca6fafbbde1c3cdc\mscorlib.ni.dll
Report Id: ff408c3f-e685-494f-afb8-f0c66a19eb8f
Faulting package full name:
Faulting package-relative application ID

what i expect is that the application crashes because something wrong in the application gives me stackoverflow exception however the memory usage of the Os  is so low i dont know when it happens and also when i tried to see that path

C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\mscorlib\40571abae9422cd2ca6fafbbde1c3cdc\mscorlib.ni.dll

i didnt find in the production server i find the assembly folder has some misl files while on developemnt enviroment i found this path i dont know what is the difference  somesay its code error , others say .net framework error i cant get the solution

Comment: Sounds like a memory leak under high load. Setup a crash dump similar to what is described here (adjust setup for your scenario) - https://forum.uipath.com/t/how-to-generate-application-dumps-using-debug-diag/307354

Then, analyze the dump, along lines of - https://community.nintex.com/automation-on-prem-29/analyzing-memory-dumps-using-debugdiag-2-analysis-27566

This should point you in the right direction.

Comment: I did that already but i have an issue the debugdiag also gives me stackoverflow the more info it added to me is that i have thread id but i dont know what to do

Comment: From memory, and it's been a while I did this, you should also be able to get the stack trace that leads to the crash, which likely will point to your app code, where you can check further.

Comment: The dumps captured with DebugDiag must be further analyzed so as to find out what's the culprit. That kind of analysis is expensive, and Stack Overflow isn't likely to help you further.

Comment: I have done so but the error was so generic its stackoverflow but i cant get the piece of code do that

Comment: Based on the complex environment you mentioned, it is difficult for us to reproduce this issue, I suggest you open a ticket via: https://support.microsoft.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after a month of searching and non sleeping i found the solution was so easy i installed debug diag,then i use debugdiag to track iis process and i add in exception settings full **user dump**  its so important to make the exception raise full user dump , after first crash debugdiag throws dump file in the location you chose then open debugdiagaAnalyzer.exe and start analysis after choosing memory analysis and crash analysis it will show you the thread id that crashed and thr function exactlty that made stackoverflow

Comment: Yes, Full Userdump was noted in the link I shared.